# Delete Blank Rows in an Excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete all rows where cells in column S are blank as part of a table ("`Table1`").

I receive an error "400".

This macro works if I replace `& LastRow` with a number, "S2:S1000" for example.

```
Sub deleteBlankRows()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Range("S2:S" & LastRow)
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the value of lastrow when it errors?

Comment: Interesting, just saw that.  It says "LastRow = 0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you are deleting entire rows from a table. You can convert the table to range, or use `Rows` rather than `EntireRow` in the macro:

```
Sub deleteBlankRows()

Dim LastRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName")

    LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("S2:S" & LastRow)
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Rows.Delete
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Only reason why I have it in a table is to keep the data connection (SQL Query).  Is it possible to keep using a SQL query if I convert it to a range?
Also, I still receive the "400" error with the .Rows, or were you referring to using that in a converted range.

Comment: @AspiringDeveloper No, `.Rows` is for tables. It seems your `LastRow` is not picked up correctly. I've edited the code and please let me know if you still get the error.

Comment: This is baffling me, I still receive the "400" error.

Comment: @AspiringDeveloper If you add worksheet reference in the code?

Comment: Still received the 400 error.  I'm sorry, never intended this post to be this frustrating.

Comment: Found the issue.  These cells weren't "blank", they had 6 spaces in each of them.  After getting rid of the rogue spaces (trim), worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the rows you want to delete are **only** in the table, you can also work directly with the table object itself.

```
With ListObjects("Table1")
     .ListColumns("myColumnName").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Rows.Delete 
End With
```

Comment: I received "Sub or Function Not Defined" error and it highlights ListObjects

Comment: And yes, the values to delete are ONLY within the table.

Comment: @AspiringDeveloper - my bad, I misnamed the table as `Table` instead of `Table1`